# How to loop through JSON data in wordpress WP REST API

Tags: php, json, wp-api, rest-api

I am using the WP REST API plugin in wordpress and want to loop through my json data using a for each loop, however when I var_dump the variable that the json data is stored in it gives me an error.

"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) in C:\wamp\www\public_html\wp-content\themes\raj\template-wiki.php on line 22"

```
<?php $json = lusso_posts(); ?>

<?php var_dump($json); ?>

<?php echo ($json->wp-json->posts[1]->ID); ?>
```

I think the "wp-json" is conflicting with "->" this sign because when I remove the "-" from "wp-post", the error goes away but nothing shows.

CODE FROM LUSSO FUNCTION

`    function lusso_posts() {

```
  // Do we have this information in our transients already?
  $transient = get_transient( 'lusso_posts' );

  // Yep!  Just return it and we're done.
  if( ! empty( $transient ) ) {

    // The function will return here every time after the first time it is   run, until the transient expires.
    return $transient;

  // Nope!  We gotta make a call.
  } else {

    // We got this url from the documentation for the remote API.
    $url = 'http://localhost/database2/wp-json/posts/';

    $body =  wp_remote_retrieve_body(wp_remote_get($url));

    $json = json_decode($body);


    // Call the API.
    //$out = wp_remote_get( $url, $args );

    // Save the API response so we don't have to call again until  tomorrow.
    set_transient( 'lusso_posts', $json, DAY_IN_SECONDS );

    // Return the list of subscribers.  The function will return here the first time it is run, and then once again, each time the transient expires.
    return $json;

  }

}`
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the output of your `var_dump($json)`? Can you try `echo ($json->{'wp-json'}->posts[1]->ID);`?

Comment: The output of `var_dump($json)` is my wordpress blog posts in json format. 
I tried your solution and even tried to `var_dump` it and it returns null value :(

Comment: Check if `$json` is valid (object/not null) and then echo.

Comment: Does `wp-json` show up in your var_dump? Is line 22 the var_dump or the echo? What does your `lusso_posts` code look like?

Comment: This is my code for the Lusso function - im using a transient to get post data from another website and show it on my own website by caching it.

See my edit on my post;

Comment: @czerspalace - If you download the WP REST API plugin for wordpress and access it, I then want to use the transient script to get jsn formartted data from one site and show it on my own website. For this i just set up 2 wordpress websites locally - one acting as an external and one acting as my own. 

in my own website, I want to loop from the lusso function to get the json format from the external website and show on my own website.

Comment: You may be accessing your data wrong. What if you try `echo ($json->posts[0]->ID);` do you see anything?

Comment: hi, it displays Null. I managed to access the json data using a foreach loop

'    ?php  
     foreach($json as $post){
  echo $post->title."</br>";
  echo '<img src"$post->featured_image->guid">';
     }

     ?>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this and access the JSON data using a `foreach` loop:

```
$json = lusso_posts();
#var_dump( $json );
#die();

foreach( $json as $post ) { 
    $titles = $post->title;
    $images = $post->featured_image->guid;
    ?>
    <div class="lusso-posts">
        <div class="image-container"><img src="<?php echo $images; ?>" />    </div>
        <h4><?php echo $titles; ?></h4>
    </div>  
    <?php
}
```